# Ambiance Theme was deleted /missing from Ubuntu 13.10. How to re-intall default theme?

Tags: 13.10, themes, ambiance

I must have done something wrong. I un-installed Nginx and PHP-FPM using apt-get purge. When I did a reboot, the theme changed from Ambiance to High Contrast. Also the Audacious player is also gone. The Ambiance theme is not available anymore from the settings. How can I get the Ambiance theme back? thanks. I am using Ubuntu 13.10. I hate the High Contrast theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install light-themes audacious
```

Then restart your system.

From theme manager you can now choose ambiance theme and audacious also installs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hey. the terminal is not working either. it looks like windows' cmd. but i could not paste anything.

Comment: use ctrl+shift+v to paste @freeloader

Comment: @freeloader most welcome

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the packages `light-themes` and `dmz-cursor-theme` for the ambiance theme.