# How to bring back the default graphics

Tags: default

I just uninstalled all cairo dock related stuffs from my ubuntu 13.10 using 'purge remove' and now my present graphics(colors and stuff) are way different from my default(when I installed it). Can someone please explain what shall I do to bring it back to default settings.

Comment: Try `unity --reset` - and could you possible post a screens-hot of your desktop? This might also be a theme issues. Meaning you need to set it to default. Right click > change background and below the images you can set it to the theme of your choice

Comment: but only high contrast theme is showing, so can u tell me how to restore default theme.

Comment: To reset the theme to the default one question has already been answered, and can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/a/194922/36315

Comment: Thanks worked, but it is not the default ambiance theme. It is kind of grey and boxy.

Comment: Are u using gnome? or unity? or something else?

Comment: I have unity tweak

Comment: what desktop environment are you using?

Comment: srry, whats desktop environment

Comment: I think its unity

Comment: Hey, thanks for your kind time, it got solved by http://askubuntu.com/questions/394709/ambiance-theme-was-deleted-missing-from-ubuntu-13-10-how-to-re-intall-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, search for software and updates then click on additional drivers you will see a list there. Choose the driver you want.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but how to restore the default ubuntu theme ?

Answer (score 1):

To reset the theme open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ''

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme ''

gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/theme ''
```

Comment: After run this command logout and login back.

Comment: Thanks worked but it is not the default ambiance theme.